# Term describing the smallest possible unit of data

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, technical, programming

I want to write something like:

> In cases where the smallest unit of data is available (e.g. houses, persons, vehicles), we can use more detailed models.

So I am looking for something describing non-averaged and specific data.
However, I'd like to use a less bulky / more professional expression. Things that sound kind of ok to me (as a non-native speaker), but are maybe misleading:

> In cases **atomic** data is available (e.g. houses, persons, vehicles), we can use more detailed models.

or

> In cases where **bottom-up** data is available (e.g. houses, persons, vehicles), we can use more detailed models.

As this is obviously a technical description of databases, the term can be "borrowed" from programming languages (as I did in my "atomic" example).

Comment: I didn't know Democritus was a programmer.

Comment: @HotLicks :D Good point. So would you vote for atomic?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to describe.  Would "per-unit data" be a better fit?

Comment: It might be a fit, but seems less "professional" maybe...  The opposite would be "aggregated or averaged data"

Comment: Actually, "individual" might work.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too. To me it feels a bit weird, like something was missing. Maybe make it an answer and we see what the votes say :)

Comment: In cases where *raw, non-aggregated* data is available...

Comment: It depends on your target group. If you are addressing statisticians and people used to dealing with statistical information then 'atomic data' would be fine, if you are addressing the general public then you would be better off using the full explanation. There are many members of the public for whom the words 'atomic' and 'nuclear' only mean scary bombs and leaky power stations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is very ambiguous. In title, you are asking `smallest possible unit of data`. The *smallest possible unit of data* is called a **bit**.

In the blockquote example you are stating `...where the smallest unit of data is available (e.g. houses, persons, vehicles)...`. If you are pointing to a specific element of data, then it is called **datum**. A datum is a single unit of data or to say, singular form of the word data.

On the other hand, in the description you are asking something on the lines of `(something) non-averaged and specific data`. Well, in DBMS, *non-averaged* and *specific data* is called **atomic data** and there is no specific synonym for that term. If you want to use the word **quantum**, then go ahead, but remember, **quantum of data** means smallest data and need not necessary means *non-averaged*.

Comment: Thank you for the very exact answer. I wasn't sure if atomic would accessible enough, but your answer tells me that it is probably the best choice here.

Comment: A bit is not the smallest unit of data. If you are uncertain about the state of a system, you can have a fraction of a bit of information about it.

Comment: Suppose I have a system with two states, A and B. If I have no idea which state the system is in, I have no information (0 bits). If I know the system is in state A, I have 1 bit of information about the system. If I know the system is in state B, I have 1 bit of information about the system. But if I know the system is 90% likely to be in state A and only 10% likely to be in state B, I have somewhat less information, a fraction of a bit of information.

Comment: Digital computers should never get into states where they store fractional bits, but quantum computers can.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory

Comment: @ThePhoton you are mixing up too much. I'll make it simple for you, in computer science the smallest unit of data is bit. It is not about philosophical aspect of the subject. Also, `But if I know the system is 90% likely to be in state A and only 10% likely to be in state B` then you have 100% (90+ 10) of information, that is an entire bit (actually, these much information more than just a bit).

Comment: You asked me to substantiate my claim, and now you ask me to delete the information that does that?

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, your claiming something which is entirely out of the context. You are discussing QC here. You should keep in mind that OP is asking question on ELU related to classical computer field: DBMS.

Comment: @ThePhoton if you want to argue about bit being smallest unit or not, then I advice you to put a separate question on SE CS and we can discuss there. I hope you understand.

Comment: I consider your answer and the way you deal with comments aggressive and at the limit of being non-constructive. If you think my question needs improving, I would appreciate a hint on how to best do that.

Comment: @n1000 no, it's not about you or your question.  It is about The Photon guy, discussing quantum computer here.

Answer (score -1):

One term for this, related to *atomic*, is ***[quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum)***. Wikipedia gives a summary of it as "a quantum ... is the minimum amount of any physical entity (physical property) involved in an interaction."

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Will it work as an adjective?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to convey, since houses, persons, and vehicles are not kinds of data.

If you mean to say that they might have data on neighborhoods or counties, but it would be better if they have data on individual houses, I might call this

- detailed data
- specific data
- fine-grained data

In any case, in context it's likely that the examples you give (houses, persons, vehicles) will make it clear to your readers what you mean.